# jQuery delegate on table td except first td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to delegate a click event to all `td`'s except first td. I tried following codes, but none of them worked:

```
$(function(){
   $('#table1').on('click','td:gt(0)',function(){
      alert($(this).text());
   });
});
$(function(){
   $('#table1').on('click','td:not(:first)',function(){
      alert($(this).text());
   });
});
$(function(){
   $('#table1').on('click','td:not(:nth-child(1))',function(){
      alert($(this).text());
   });
});
```

**UPDATE**

OK sorry, the last one is working. I won't delete the question just in case other people may need.

Comment: you should use the last one, other solutions won't work of course. The `:gt(0)` will just exclude the first `td` of the first row, the `:not(:first)` is the same.

Comment: working.. http://jsfiddle.net/7U3tm/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy no, it just works for the first row, try this instead http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/7U3tm/1/

Comment: @KingKing yeah, i just realized that.. nth-child would be the best choice.